# How to enforce HTTPS for static content with Tomcat + Spring Security

Tags: spring, tomcat, https

I have a Spring 4.1.1, Spring security 3.2.5, JSF 2.2.3 web application that runs on a Tomcat 8 server.

I need everything, including all static content, to be accessible exclusively through HTTPS.

I managed to do this for the dynamic content but the static content is still accessible directly through HTTP, e.g. with the URL `http://localhost:8080/static/images/image.png`. I need this also to be redirected to HTTPS.

> **server.xml**

```
<Connector connectionTimeout="20000" port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1" redirectPort="8443"/>

<Connector port="8443" SSLEnabled="true"
    maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
    enableLookups="true" disableUploadTimeout="true"
    acceptCount="100" debug="0" scheme="https" secure="true"
    clientAuth="false" sslProtocol="TLSv1"
    keystoreFile="C:/Java/jdk1.8.0_40/bin/keystore.jks"
    keystorePass="xxx" />
```

> **web.xml**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Automatic HTTPS Redirect</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
  </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
  <web-resource-collection>
      <web-resource-name>Restricted Methods</web-resource-name>
      <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
      <http-method>PUT</http-method>
      <http-method>DELETE</http-method>
      <http-method>TRACE</http-method>
      <http-method>OPTIONS</http-method>
  </web-resource-collection>
  <auth-constraint />
</security-constraint>
```

> **spring_security.xml** (abridged version)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans >
    <!-- Configure Spring Security -->
    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
      <security:authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <security:password-encoder ref="passwordEncoderBean">
            <security:salt-source ref="saltSource"/>
        </security:password-encoder>
      </security:authentication-provider>
    </security:authentication-manager>  

    <bean id="saltSource" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.ReflectionSaltSource" >
        <property name="userPropertyToUse" value="salt"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="passwordEncoderBean" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.encoding.ShaPasswordEncoder">
        <constructor-arg value="256" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService" class="com.pippo.security.UserDetailsImpl"/>

    <bean id="authenticationProcessingFilter" class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter">  
        <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
        <property name="authenticationFailureHandler" ref="failureHandler" />
        <property name="authenticationSuccessHandler" ref="successHandler" />
        <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/spring/loginProcess"/>
    </bean>  

    <bean id="successHandler" class="com.pippo.security.pippoAuthenticationSuccessHandler" >
        <property name="defaultTargetUrl" value="/spring/flows/client_main_flow" />
        <property name="roleManager" ref="roleManager" />
        <property name="geoIPManager" ref="geoIPManager" />
        <constructor-arg>
            <map value-type="java.lang.String" key-type="java.lang.String">
                <entry key="ROLE_ADMIN" value="/spring/flows/admin_main_flow"/>
                <entry key="ROLE_ANON" value="/spring/flows/public"/>
                <entry key="DENIED" value="/spring/flows/access_denied"/>
            </map>
        </constructor-arg>
    </bean>
    <bean id="failureHandler" class="com.pippo.security.CustomAuthenticationFailureHandler" >
        <property name="defaultFailureUrl" value="/pippo" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="authenticationEntryPoint"  class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint">
        <property name="loginFormUrl" value="/spring/flows/public"/>
    </bean>

    <security:http entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" pattern="/spring/**">
        <security:anonymous />
        <security:http-basic />
        <security:custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="authenticationProcessingFilter" />
        <security:logout logout-url="/spring/logout" success-handler-ref="logoutController"/>
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/login" access="ROLE_ANON,ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/logoutSuccess" access="ROLE_ANON,ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/intro" access="ROLE_ANON,ROLE_USER"  />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/spring/flows/admin_main_flow/**" access="ROLE_ADMIN" />
    </security:http>

    <security:http security="none" pattern="/javax.faces.resource/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/ajax/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/static/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/resources/**" />
    <security:http security="none" pattern="/spring/flows/public/**" />

    <bean id="logoutController" class="com.pippo.security.LogoutHandlerImpl"/>

  <bean id="eventDispatcher" class="com.pippo.listener.EventDispatcher"/>

</beans>
```

Please note that if I load any page that contains secure references to static content such as CSS or JavaScript files or images, all the static content is retrieved correctly over HTTPS. The problem is for direct URLs to the static content, like the above (`http://localhost:8080/static/images/image.png`) that should be redirected to HTTPS but are not.

I also tried to add an intercept URL in place of `security none`, but it didn't work either:

```
<security:http pattern="/static/**" entry-point-ref="authenticationEntryPoint" use-expressions="true">
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/static/**" requires-channel="https" access="permitAll"/>
</security:http>
```

I guess the Tomcat configuration is incorrect, but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2):

`<security:http security="none" pattern="url-pattern" />` means that Spring Security will not intercept any request that follows the pattern matching `url-pattern`.  Therefore, your static resource URLs drop out of purview of the Spring Security framework.

In order to achieve the desired behaviour, the configuration should be changed to:

```
<security:intercept-url access="permitAll" pattern="url-pattern" requires-channel="https"/>
```

This configuration signifies that all users should be allowed to access URLs matching the pattern `url-pattern`, and HTTPS should be enforced for those URLs.